# Altering font size using label expression?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, labeling, annotation, maplex

I have two label classes displaying dynamically over my parcel polygons. The owner info is the major label with larger font size and bellow it I am displaying some property type info in smaller font.

The problem is that the 2 label classes just will not display the way I want them to; Major label at the top, minor label just bellow it.  I've used maplex and the regular labeling engine and played with the options but it just does not do what I want and the labels jump all over the parcels.

The only way that works is to export the labels into a feature linked annotation size then adjust the label positions manually.  This is OK but i need to change the scale often on this map.

**Can I write the label expression so that I can have 2 different fonts and sizes within one label?**  (Something similar to using text tags with text graphics)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes! One can definitely set different font sizes for different fields within a single label.
Please see this Link: http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00s800000027000000.htm

Look at the font attribute. You can set a particular size for the important part of the label and a smaller size for the less important part.

Comment: The **text formatting tags** section of that link quickly answers this question. +1 for that, and all of the additional, useful info. the link offers.

Answer (score 6):

I should be reading the help more often...

Yes I can: `"<FNT name='Arial' size='18'>" & [LABELFIELD] & "</FNT>"`

Comment: how does that change the size?

Comment: It changes size where it says size = '18'

Comment: yes, u r correct; I put in the earlier comment before you put in the font tags.

Comment: affirmative @Devdatta.